# Multiple Async Execution NodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, function, async-await

I have updated the code snippet per suggestion:

```html
const fs = require('fs');
const replaceExt = require('replace-ext');


function newFile() {
    const directoryFile = fs.readdirSync('./zipped').toString();
    const direArray = directoryFile.split(',');
    console.log(direArray);
    return Promise.resolve(direArray);
    //console.log(typeof direArray);
    //console.log(directoryFile);
}

function dirArr(direArray) {
    direArray.forEach((directoryFile) => {
        fs.rename('./zipped/' + directoryFile, replaceExt('./zipped/' + directoryFile, '.zip'), function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(directoryFile)
        });
    })
}
```

In a nutshell I am attempting to:
Function "newFile()"
-  Read the contents of a directory
-  Change the filename/names from ".par" to ".zip"
-  Return array of newly renamed files
Function "dirArr()"
-  Use return output from "newFile()", i.e. array of ".zip" file names
-  **Have not started this part yet**
   -  Iterate through array of ".zip" filenames and perform another async unzip 
      task

I am still learning this stuff and make every attempt to figure it out myself before coming to S.O. for help.  So I believe you when you say there are items which do not make sense and could be written more eloquently.  I am a newb and still learning unfortunately.....Again all of you help is appreciated....

Comment: Use the `fs.promises` interface to be able to use `fs` function that return promises.  `async` does you no good if you're not working with promises.

Comment: When I attempted to use fsPromises I get an npm error saying it is not in the registry.  I did not know it was absolutely necessary to use it for fs async callback.  Since I am unable to get fsPromises what other options do I have?

Comment: Its `const fsp = require('fs').promises;`.  It's all in the nodejs doc.  Nothing new to install.

Comment: `I get undefined for both of the console.log entries` you don't return any value from those functions, so `readDirValue` and `strArrValue` will naturally be `undefined` ... just like a *regular* function, if you don't return anything, you are effectively doing `return undefined`

Comment: Also, `execAsyncTasks().then();` ?? no need to call .then since you aren't passing a function to `.then` ...

Comment: This code is really off-base in a whole bunch of ways.  Can you describe what you're trying to accomplish here?  In words, what is the input and output supposed to be?

Comment: If you look at just `strArr()` it calls `fs.readdirSync()` which returns an array of filenames.  You then convert that to a string, then you split it back into an array.  That makes no sense at all.  It comes right out of `fs.readdirSync()` as an array.  And, if you're really going to use `fs.readdirSync()`, that's synchronous so there's no reason for that to be in an `async` function at all.  Then, you don't return anything from the function so all it does is log something, nothing else.

Comment: If you look at `readDir()` it gets an array of filenames, converts that array to a string and then tries to combine that string with a path and call `fs.rename()`.  That makes no sense.  It might have a chance of working if there was only one file in the directory, but has no chance of ever working if there's multiple files in the directory.  If you want to rename them all, you will have to loop over the array of filenames.

Comment: @jfriend00 -  You are correct...At first I was going to have only 1 file in this directory which would need to be renamed from ".par" file extension to ".zip" file extension.  Thinking back over it I have added a "for each" loop that can handle multiple files in an array and loops through to rename them all.  So if there is 1 file it will simply rename it, however if there are multiple files it will rename all within the array.  I am still facing same issue of calling async functions via Promises/Callbacks.  I have updated the code snippet from the original posting to show what I have thus far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an implementation that uses the promise-based version of the `fs` library that is available as

```
require('fs').promises;
```

I've coded two functions.  The first function lists files in a directory and returns a promise that resolves to an array of fully qualified paths.  The second function renames those files with a new file extension and returns a promise that resolves to an array of the renamed paths.

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');
const replaceExt = require('replace-ext');

// takes an argument that specifies the directory to list
// returns a promise that resolves to a list of files in that directory
function listFiles(dir) {
    // make dir into a fully qualified path
    let fullDir = path.resolve(dir);
    return fsp.readdir(fullDir).then(files => {
        // make into full path
        return files.map(f => {
            return path.join(fullDir, f);
        });
    });
}

// takes an array of filenames and a new file extension
// renames all the files to have the new extension
// returns array of new filenames
async function renameFiles(files, newExt) {
    // build array of renamed filenames
    const  newFiles = files.map(f => {
        return replaceExt(f, newExt);
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        await fsp.rename(files[i], newFiles[i]);
    }
    return newFiles;
}


// Example usage
listFiles("./zipped").then(files => {
    return renameFiles(files, ".zip");
}).then(newFiles => {
    console.log(newFiles);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do.  I will be going over it to see where my missteps were.  Thanks for you help I assure you it will be used for reference and learning.